# php express checkout recurring created profile successfully but recurring not working

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

we have implemented express checkout very well.
we get ipn response for each transaction.
we done these thing in sandbox.

now we are making recurring payment with express checkout.
here the recurring profile is creating proper,
But i am not getting any ipn notification for transaction and also not any transaction is done for that profile.

Can anyone suggest me solution for this issue.

Help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

vijay

Answer (score 0):

Recurring Payments transactions send IPN's just fine, so my guess is your IPN script must not be handling them correctly or maybe just "doing nothing" with them.  For example, if you're only handling a specific txn_type, then you might be missing out on other stuff.

Log in to your PayPal account and check your IPN History and you should see a list of all the IPN's it's been sending.  You can see if it's returning Success or Fail, there, because another possibility is that your IPN script is simply failing when a certain txn_type hits it.

Your own web server logs can be a big help when troubleshooting that sort of thing, too.  If you are getting some IPN's, though, it would be sending them all, so something must be going on to make you think they're not sending when they are.

Comment: transation not doing in recurring profile that is created. i checked at sandbox paypal transaction and both ipn history